# plotly: The shape palette can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values

Tags: r, r-plotly

I used the library `plotly` to produce a plot (PCA) and everything works fine except I get this message:

> Warning message:
> The shape palette can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values because
> more than 6 becomes difficult to discriminate; you have 33. Consider
> specifying shapes manually if you must have them.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Note: The plot of land is produced normally, but I hope that this message does not appear.

This is the code I used:

```
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~PC1, y = ~PC2, color = ~data$Population,
              colors = c("#FFFF00", "#1CE6FF", "#FF34FF", "#FF4A46", "#008941", "#006FA6", "#A30059","#FFDBE5","#7A4900", " #0000A6", "#63FFAC", "#B79762", "#004D43", "#8FB0FF", "#997D87","#5A0007", "#809693", "#FEFFE6", "#1B4400", " #4FC601","#3B5DFF","#4A3B53","#FF2F80","#61615A","#BA0900","#6B7900","#00C2A0","#FFAA92","#FF90C9"," #B903AA", "#D16100","#DDEFFF", "#A1C299", "#0AA6D8", "#013349", "#00846F", "#FFB500", "#C2FFED", "#A079BF"," #CC0744","#C0B9B2","#C2FF99","#00489C","#6F0062","#0CBD66","#EEC3FF","#456D75","#B77B68","#7A87A1","#7A87A1"," #788D66", "#885578", "#FAD09F", "#FF8A9A", "#D157A0", "#BEC459","#456648","#0086ED","#886F4C","#B4A8BD","#B4A8BD"," #00A6AA", "#636375", "#A3C8C9", "#FF913F", "#938A81","#575329", "#00FECF", "#B05B6F", "#8CD0FF", "#3B9700", " #04F757", "#C8A1A1", "#1E6E00","#7900D7", "#A77500", "#6367A9", "#A05837", "#6B002C", "#772600", "#D790FF", " #9B9700","#549E79","#FFF69F","#72418F","#BC23FF","#99ADC0","#3A2465","#922329"),
               marker = list(size = 10),mode = 'markers', symbol = ~Population, symbols = c('circle','circle-open','square','0','diamond','diamond-open ','cross','cross-open','x','x-open','triangle-up','triangle-up-open','triangle-down','triangle-down-open', 'triangle-left', 'triangle-left-open', 'triangle-right', 'triangle-right-open', 'triangle-ne', 'triangle-ne-open', 'triangle-se','triangle -se-open','triangle-sw','triangle-sw-open','triangle-nw', 'triangle-nw-open', 'pentagon', 'pentagon-open', 'hexagon','hexagon -open','hexagon2','hexagon2-open','star','star-open','hexagram', 'hexagram-open','star-triangle-up','star-triangle-up-open ','star-triangle-down','star-triangle-down-open','star-square','star-square-open','star-diamond','star-diamond-open','diamond -tall','diamond-tall-open','diamond-wide','diamond-wide-open','hourglass','hourglass-open','bowtie','bowtie-open','circle-cross -open','circle-x-open','square-cross-open','square-x-open', 'diamond-cross-open','diamond-x-open', 'cross-thin-open' ','x-thin-open','as terisk-open', 'hash-open', 'y-up-open', 'y-down-open', 'y-left-open', 'y-right-open', 'arrow-up',' arrow-up-open','arrow-down','arrow-down-open','arrow-left','arrow-left-open','arrow-right','arrow-right-open',' arrow-bar-up', 'arrow-bar-up-open', 'arrow-bar-down', 'arrow-bar-down-open', 'arrow-bar-left', 'arrow-bar-left- open','arrow-bar-right','arrow-bar-right-open')) %>%
layout(title = "Custom Hover Text",
         legend = list(title = list(text = "<b>Cylinders</b>"),itemsizing='constant')) %>%

    add_markers()
p
```

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? What code produced this issue for you, and what does your current output look like?

Comment: Add the code I used.

Comment: Can you add the sample data using `dput` to recreate the problem?

Comment: I believe you are looking for [this](https://plotly-r.com/working-with-symbols.html#:~:text=28-,Working%20with%20symbols%20and%20glyphs,-The%20JavaScript%20library)

Comment: Hi @Max. Welcome to SO! Note that this is not an error message but just a warning message indicating that choosing more than 6 discrete values may alter the readability of the graph. Therefore, I think it is up to you to choose according to the final rendering of your plot.